# rEFInd editing boot entry

Tags: uefi, refind

I got an odd problem with rEFInd when attempting to edit a boot entry from the menu. Basically, everything seems to work. I select the relevant menu entry and press `tab` to get into refinds editor which allows me to do my edits. However, after pressing `enter` to boot with the new kernel parameters, it summarizes that is about to start vmlinux, prints the boot options and stops there.

I'm certain the edits are correct, if hard coding them into another menu item, refind will happily boot. And also, the problem seems to be deeper than the kernel parameters themself. Meaning, if I enter the editor, making no changes, and just press enter to boot, again, refind halts exactly as described above, even though no changes have been made.

I'm wondering if anybody in here has had similar experiences with refind? and if so, what they did to resolve them?

Comment: Might be just a bug, try emailing Roderick -- he's one of the best upstreams in my downstream experience (I've packaged refind for ALT Linux, his UEFI docs helped me a lot to introduce the support).